# Figuring out who has authenticated with basicAuth on Node while processing a POST request

Tags: ajax, node.js, rest, authentication

I am using basicAuth to authenticate POSTs on a specific address.

On the client side I am using a command of the form:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        accepts: "text/plain",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/somewhere",
        data: JSON.stringify(something),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            window.alert("Received back: '" + data + "'");
        },
        username: theUsername,
        password: "a password"
    });
```

This is working fine, in the sense that the username stored in theUsername passes the authentication mechanism that I have on node. While the user is authenticated I can print a console.log statement and see who has actually authenticated (I am not validating the password at the moment). But then the actual processing starts for the POST request. However, at that point how can I figure out the username and the password used in the original request? I tried to look on the headers of the request but I don't see anything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you receive a Basic authentication request you should be able to read the "authorization" header in `req.headers.authorization` You have to pull out the the base64 encoded credentials and then decode them. Presumably, in Express you use `req.header("authorization")` or `req.get("authorization")`

For a standalone example, take a look at https://gist.github.com/charlesdaniel/1686663 which I have copied underneath for future reference

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        // console.log(req);   // debug dump the request

        // If they pass in a basic auth credential it'll be in a header called "Authorization" (note NodeJS lowercases the names of headers in its request object)

        var auth = req.headers['authorization'];  // auth is in base64(username:password)  so we need to decode the base64
        console.log("Authorization Header is: ", auth);

        if(!auth) {     // No Authorization header was passed in so it's the first time the browser hit us

                // Sending a 401 will require authentication, we need to send the 'WWW-Authenticate' to tell them the sort of authentication to use
                // Basic auth is quite literally the easiest and least secure, it simply gives back  base64( username + ":" + password ) from the browser
                res.statusCode = 401;
                res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');

                res.end('<html><body>Need some creds son</body></html>');
        }

        else if(auth) {    // The Authorization was passed in so now we validate it

                var tmp = auth.split(' ');   // Split on a space, the original auth looks like  "Basic Y2hhcmxlczoxMjM0NQ==" and we need the 2nd part

                var buf = new Buffer(tmp[1], 'base64'); // create a buffer and tell it the data coming in is base64
                var plain_auth = buf.toString();        // read it back out as a string

                console.log("Decoded Authorization ", plain_auth);

                // At this point plain_auth = "username:password"

                var creds = plain_auth.split(':');      // split on a ':'
                var username = creds[0];
                var password = creds[1];

                if((username == 'hack') && (password == 'thegibson')) {   // Is the username/password correct?

                        res.statusCode = 200;  // OK
                        res.end('<html><body>Congratulations you just hax0rd teh Gibson!</body></html>');
                }
                else {
                        res.statusCode = 401; // Force them to retry authentication
                        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');

                        // res.statusCode = 403;   // or alternatively just reject them altogether with a 403 Forbidden

                        res.end('<html><body>You shall not pass</body></html>');
                }
        }
});


server.listen(5000, function() { console.log("Server Listening on http://localhost:5000/"); });
```

Comment: I bypassed this problem in the following sense. In the documentation (http://expressjs.com/api.html#basicAuth) it mentions the req.user will be used to write down the user. However, it really writes down the return value of the authorization function. So, I am returning false when someone is not authorized, and otherwise I am returning the username. Then, through req.user I can have access to the username that was authorized. Clearly, I could have returned a struct with the username and the password and get both of them. Thanks for your time anyway. I am accepting because of your effort.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer is probably helpful to others who might find this question. For future reference, Node !== Express :). And yes, with Express you could return the full user credentials as an object and this would become the value of req.user